# Node does not start syncing

Tags: node

I had the node fully synced just a couple of days ago and had to restart several times while working on things. Now it wont start syncing and keeps throwing these same errors - any ideas on how to fix?

Of course I don't wanna delete 80+ Gb context + data chain! Running in docker container installed from tezos mainnet.sh. Box has 20gb free ram, cpu and enough disk. Running on latest protocol 003-PsddFKi3

```
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idsjspFRxYWD
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error, dumping error stack:
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Worker crashed:
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:11 - validator.peer(276): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idsn9he7cC2z
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error, dumping error stack:
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Worker crashed:
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:15 - validator.peer(277): Not_found
Feb 21 00:44:17 - node.main: Received the TERM signal, triggering shutdown.
Feb 21 00:44:17 - node.main: Shutting down the Tezos node...
Feb 21 00:44:17 - validator.chain(1): Worker terminated
Feb 21 00:44:17 - validator.block: Worker terminated
Feb 21 00:44:17 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ(1): Worker terminated
Feb 21 00:44:17 - node.main: Shutting down the RPC server...
Feb 21 00:44:17 - node.main: BYE (-11)
```

Comment: What is your platform ? Which is the commit hash of your build ? Did you move the context folder ? Is your disk full ? Are you using a docker ? Give more context pls otherwise it is hard to help you

Comment: it running in docker on alipine .. i didnt build used the mainent.sh on tezos tech doc site as i said it was synced and running fine. Install everything with docker-compose ..no i didn't move context folder..disk has plenty of space running on latest protocol 003-PsddFKi3

Comment: Update your question to give context pls instead of responding in the comments. Better to improve your question to make it as clear as possible pls

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an inconsistency in the database. Once a block has been validated by the node and stored in the `store` database, its context is supposed to be stored in the `context` database. It looks like the error messages say that the node cannot find the context of a block. It's probably because the two databases are not synchronized anymore, probably the `store` database has blocks that the `context` does not have.

You should remove the `store` database, it will restart synchronizing from the beginning. For more security, you might also remove the `context` database, in case there are more errors inside.